# Heroku: No Slack notifications for automatic deploys through GitHub

Tags: github, heroku, slack

My team has a Ruby on Rails site deployed to Heroku. I had configured Slack to get notifications when the site was deployed, which worked as long as we were deploying from the CLI. However, I recently decided to automate the deploy process using the GitHub integration such that code is automatically deployed when merged to master. Since then, we've stopped seeing Slack notifications when new code deploys.

Is this normal? Is there a way to get notifications when the app deploys through GitHub? This is a severe inconvenience to my team, but then again, so was having to manually deploy every little thing.

Comment: Any Errors that are displayed in heroku?

Comment: It ended up being expected behavior, @MatejMecka. I guess you have to set up the notifications again after you change the deployment method.

Comment: @DanaScheider would you be able to explain or point to how you set up your notifications when it was from the CLI? we have a Rails app on Heroku with some custom Ruby for deploys (that uses the CLI) and I want to add Slack notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not actually being an error. The issue turned out to be that you need to re-configure the notifications when you change the deployment method.